# tess-two won't initialise, even with correct permissions

Tags: android, tess-two

Here's what I'm currently doing:

- tess-two is set up in my Android project

[image: File directory with tess-two installed]

- I have permissions specified in the AndroidManifest.xml of my main app (not the tess-two AndroidManifest.xml):

[image: Permissions]

- I also check for permissions explicitly in my code:

  ```
  int readPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
  int writePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

  // Check we have both read and write permissions
  if (readPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
          || writePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
  {
      // We don't have permission so prompt the user
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
              this,
              new String[] {READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
              REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
      );
  }
  else
  {
      Log.d(TAG, "Read and write external permissions granted");
      initTess();
  }
  ```
- Try to initialise the TessBaseAPI:

  ```
  private void initTess()
  {
      // Check we have the eng.traineddata file in the correct place
      mTessDataPath = getFilesDir() + "/tesseract/";
      checkTessFile(new File(mTessDataPath + "tessdata/"));

      // Initialise TessBaseAPI
      mTess = new TessBaseAPI();
      mTess.init(mTessDataPath, "eng");
  }

  private void checkTessFile(File dir)
  {
      // Check if directory already exists
      if (dir.exists())
      {
          // Check if file already exists
          String dataFilePath = mTessDataPath + "tessdata/eng.traineddata";
          File datafile = new File(dataFilePath);

          if (!datafile.exists())
          {
              // If file doesn't exist, copy it over from assets folder
              copyTessFiles();
          }
      }
      else
      {
          if (dir.mkdirs())
          {
              // If directory doesn't exist, but we can create it, copy file from assets folder
              copyTessFiles();
          }
      }
  }

  private void copyTessFiles()
  {
      try
      {
          // Location we want the file to be at
          String filepath = mTessDataPath + "tessdata/eng.traineddata";

          // Get access to AssetManager
          AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

          // Open byte streams for reading/writing
          InputStream instream = assetManager.open("tessdata/eng.traineddata");
          OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(filepath);

          // Copy the file to the location specified by filepath
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          int read;
          while ((read = instream.read(buffer)) != -1)
          {
              outstream.write(buffer, 0, read);
          }
          outstream.flush();
          outstream.close();
          instream.close();
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
  {
      switch (requestCode)
      {
          case REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
          {
              if (grantResults.length > 0
                      && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
              {
                  // Initialise Tesseract API
                  initTess();
              }

              return;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

When I run the app, I get the following error in my logs:

```
E/Tesseract(native): Could not initialize Tesseract API with language=eng!
```

I have no idea where to go from here, so any help or advise would be hugely appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: Where is your onRequestPermissionsResult method where you handle the permission?

Comment: I've edited the question to show this, and added the call to the initTess() method if we already have both permissions (which I do).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not initialize Tesseract API with language=eng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291379/could-not-initialize-tesseract-api-with-language-eng)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the right version of the [training data files](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files#data-files-for-version-304305).